# Multiple relations in MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

As an introductory project for my school subject, I was requested to create an app for showing the list of shops in my country with the possibility to sort it by location and category. What is more, it should not be just a static text, as a user may add his/her own shops to the list.

Although I am not experiencing any problems with the UI and functionality of my Java application, I am a complete newbie to databases and, particularly, to MySQL. Even though I have scrutinized some tutorials, I still keep toiling over one indeed primitive issue.

The problem is:

I created a table "Shop" with columns "id"(the primary key with auto increment), "name"(text type), "type"(text type) and "location"(text type).

Alike, two more tables were made:

1) "Types" which contains "id" again as the primary key and "type". For example:

```
id   type
1    supermarket
2    grocery
3    bookshop
```

2) "Location" with "id" too and "city". Something like this:

```
id   city
1    London
2    Nottingham
3    Southampton
```

What I attempted to do is to create "many to 1" relation between "Types"/"Location" and "Shop" tables (or "1 to 1" between "Types" and "Shop" as well as "Location" and "Shop"), because further I would want to sort shops by location and type and, consequently, print list of relevant shops in my app. However, I simply cannot find the logical sequence how to implement those connections.

Looking forward to any tips.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given the requirement, there's no need for more than one table. Given your implementation of the first table, there's no need for the other two.

Comment: But if I adjust my tables next way: "Type" will contain type_id, "Location" - location_id and, therefore, my "Shop" table's "type" and "location" will turn into indexed "type_id" and "location_id". Or this will be just a waste of time?

Comment: A waste of time. You're just making it much more expensive and complicated to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the relationships you describe here are one-to-many:

- A shop has one and only one type. A type can be used in many different shops.
- A shop has one and only one location. A location can be used in many different shops.

An extra consideration can be made about if you allow a shop to have an empty type or location. For simplicity, we will consider that is not happening here (but it can be implemented by using nullable foreign keys).

One-to-many relationships are implemented by adding a foreign key between the two involved tables. That is made by adding a column in the child table that contains the id (primary key) of the parent table, and creating a foreign key constraint for those columns.

That is, you have to add a `typeId` column to your `Shop` table, and define the foreign key constraint in your database. Same for the relationship with locations: add a `locationId` column to `Shop` and a foreign key constraint.

You shouldn't include in your `Shop` table the text columns for location and type names, only the columns for the IDs. When using that information to search you will do queries with joins between the different related tables. Something lke this:

```
SELECT s.name, t.type, l.city
FROM Shop s
    INNER JOIN Types t ON s.typeId = t.id
    INNER JOIN Location l ON s.locationId = l.id
WHERE t.type = 'supermarket'
```

More info about joins [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx).

The SQL needed for implementing the foreign keys is different if you are creating the tables with the foreign keys already, or if you are modifying your existing tables. [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) contains examples of both approaches.

The simple case of creating the table with the foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE Shop (
    id int NOT NULL,
    name text NOT NULL, 
    typeId int NOT NULL,
    locationId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TypeShop FOREIGN KEY (typeId)
    REFERENCES Types(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_LocationShop FOREIGN KEY (locationId)
    REFERENCES Location(id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

An important remark: in MySql only the InnoDB storage engine supports foreign keys, so you must create your tables with that `ENGINE=INNODB` parameter at the end of the SQL command in order to use foreign key constraints. If you don't specify that then the default engine will be used instead of `INNODB` and your foreign keys will not work. **Update:** since version 5.5.5 InnoDB is the default engine, so unless the engine has been explicitly changed for your database you don't need the explicit engine parameter.

[This page](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/) contains a good explanation of foreign keys in MySQL (perhaps too detailed for what you need now, but you can check it for specific information).

As a best practice, name all your tables either in plural or either in singular, but use the same criteria for all. Probably you should rename table `Types` to `Type` (or either rename the other two tables to give them plural names).